# WebDriverIO transforms the text read using getText() API

Tags: javascript, selenium-webdriver, webdriver, webdriver-io

I have an element with text:

`<span class="mat-button-wrapper">Sicherheitsfrage ändern</span>`

When I want to check text, webdriver says that is wrong

`assert.strictEqual($(.mat-button-wrapper).getText(), 'Sicherheitsfrage ändern')`

In console.log this text is next **Sicherheitsfrage einrichten** but must be **Sicherheitsfrage ändern**

Why it transforms the text? Can I avoid it?

Comment: Is there one, and only one, element with `mat-button-wrapper` in its `class` attribute? Sounds a lot like you’re finding the wrong element.

Comment: yes, @JimEvans has a point here. Could you check if the words "Sicherheitsfrage einrichten" actually appear as well on the page?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Selector was good. The problem was in the account. Testing was going on another account and for this account text was anouther.